# Gitlab как организовать командную работу

Tags: git, gitlab

Есть боевой сайт. Есть тестовый, где пиляться обновы и т.п. в дальнейшем льются на бой. На бою есть репозиторий гита, в качестве удаленного юзается gitLab.
Суть вопроса: как организовать работу разработчиков? Проблема в том , что git clone не вариант на локальную машину делать. 
В моем понимании вариант такой: т.к. на бою могет править файлы не каждый человек, на тестовом делаем ветки для разрабов, там они пилять обновы, сливают их на деве, тестим, потом делаем на боевой пулл с теста..
Хотелось бы услышать варианты более опытных юзеров.

Comment: Попробуйте [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp), позволяет через ftp делать деплой разных веток по разным путя

Comment: Это всё же не дубликат, раз тут речь по gitlab - можно использовать его возможности. В гитлабе можно выбрать мастер-ветку (вроде такой термин, сейчас под рукой нет посмотреть) и на неё наложить ограничения кому делать в неё мёрдж. Кстати, а в чём вы видите проблему с тем, чтобы делать git clone локально? Не понимаю сути этой фразы, как же тогда разработчикам работать? Может имеется ввиду какая-то отдельная ветка?

Comment: @AK, конечно, gitstack принципиально отличается от gitlab в плане обеспечения доступа к хранилищам. (сарказм).

Comment: Вы можете использовать [protected branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html), чтобы ограничить доступ на merge в ветку, которая будет раскатываться на продакшн. Доступ разработчикам на продакшн в общем-то не нужен - пусть делаю на каждую фичу/фикс отдельную ветку, которую после проверки на dev отдельный сотрудник (старший программист) будет merg'ить в мастер.

Comment: Локально сайт на машине не развернуть, в силу этого вариант с git clone на локальную машину отпадает..

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос-то по-большей части в том, как организовать процесс CI/CD. Раз "сайт не развернуть локально", лично я бы сделал образ докера или манифест docker-compose если их несколько, либо docker stack, поместил бы это на gitlab (можно поднять локальный), дал бы всем разрабам права на dev-ветку. Таким образом, проект можно было бы развернуть любому локально, ну или выделить под это sandbox-сервер, где точно так же в docker разворачивать локальные копии проекта. Далее можно сделать процесс CD, но это уже другой вопрос.